# R shiny inline points

Tags: r, shiny, point

Is there any way to display an R object in text? I would like to have Shiny output something like

``Your objects are ◼, , (green triangle)''

I think the code will look like

### ui.R

```
h2("Your Object is" )
renderIcon(pch=16, col=1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by R's object? If you want to insert a small symbol, the icon() function might be what you want

Comment: Yes, something like icon. But I want to refer to points in a plot that R makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you could use `intToUtf8()` to insert a specific shape into the text and then color it with a span. See this link for Unicode codes for geometric shapes: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
      h2("Your Object is: ",
         span(style="color: green;", intToUtf8(9650)))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```